# Access req Object in Mongoose model

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

After update model I want to insert new document in activity collection

```
MySchema.post('update', function(doc, next) {
    // here i want to access req.user (current logged In user)
    ActivityLog.create({
    collectionType: 'MySchema'
    action: 'updated',
    loggedBy: req.user
}).then(function(activity) {
    return next();
});
 });
```

ActivityLog is Activity schema

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331078/mongoose-pass-req-object-to-middleware), which doesn't have a valid answer because AFAIK there isn't a solution that isn't also incredibly hacky.